# Better way to Format Currency Input editText? in android 13

Tags: android

I have created some thing like this which works fine for android 11 or below but it gives number format error in android 13 and i am unable to put the currency amount. if anyone have idea how to do the same in android 13 then please guide. Thanks for your help.

i have tried this

```
if (!s.toString().equals(gratuity)) {
                    editGratuity.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                    String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency().getSymbol());
                    String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(replaceable, "");

                    double parsed;
                    try {
                        parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        parsed = 0.00;
                    }
                    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                    formatter.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD")); // Set the currency to a specific type, e.g., USD
                    String formatted = formatter.format((parsed/100)).replaceAll("[$]", "");

                    gratuity = formatted;
                    editGratuity.setText(formatted);
                    editGratuity.setSelection(formatted.length());
                    editGratuity.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
```